# NumberFormatException Error

Tags: java, android

the code is:

```
editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editText3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
float from_value= Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
editText3.setText(" "+(from_value * 100.0));
```

And the logcat error is:

> 03-18 03:19:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(875): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""

Comment: the error message is clear: you're trying to parse an empty string to a float. Which value would you expect ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the String in editText2 is empty, so it fails to parse it as float.

A possible solution is to check if the String is empty first, and then decide about default value, another is to catch the exception:

```
float from_value;
try {
    from_value = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    from_value = 0.0; // default ??
}
```

Comment: There is another doubt. I want to display the value in `editText3` as soon as an number is entered in `editText2`. How can I do it? Please help.

Comment: the displaying value is 100 times the entered value in my case.So if the user wants to enter 10,he will first have to enter 1 and as soon as 1 is entered the EditText3 should show 100.Now 0 remains and the user enters it to make the number 10 and now the EditText3 should show 1000.

Comment: I think you'll have to extend EditText with your own class and override the `onTextChanged` method.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to avoid using try/catch if at all possible because it is not the preferred method.

The correct way to avoid this error is to stop it before it happens.

```
if (mEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    value = 0f;
} else {
    value = Float.parseFloat(mEditText.getText().toString()); 
}
```

Update: Since you are using `EditText`, the simplest way to avoid the NumberFormatException is to specify the `inputType` attribute so that it will only accept numbers. XML example: `android:inputType="number"`. Though, you may still get a value larger (or smaller) that the data type can't hold.

Then, depending on your use case, you could even step up a level by using a custom "IntEditText" or custom `InputFilter` so that you can specify a min and max, and re-use the code across apps.

Answer (score 1):

to me the best way is to do it like this:

```
editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editText3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

if(!editText2.getText().toString().matches("")){
float from_value= Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
editText3.setText(" "+(from_value * 100.0));
}
```

And also add this line to your xml for editText2

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good idea to validate the value you are reading from editText2 before parsing it to float. Make sure it is a valid number first.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are entering some non float value which is causing this error.